# ENV variable strings for php_value in php-fpm config not working

Tags: php, docker, configuration, environment-variables, fpm

I have a php-fpm config file with:

```
php_flag[display_errors] = ${PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS}
php_value[error_reporting] = ${PHP_ERROR_REPORTING}
php_flag[log_errors] = ${PHP_LOG_ERRORS}
```

and ENV variables defined:

```
PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=1
PHP_ERROR_REPORTING=E_ALL
PHP_LOG_ERRORS=1
```

If I comment out `php_value[error_reporting]` everything works as expected (errors will be displayed on screen) but when un-commented, it doesn't work.

As I have been playing, it seems like I can set any boolean value using an ENV vairable via but cannot set string values in the same way.

I have also tried various forms of quoting the string and using php_admin_value with no luck. What amI missing.

Running: Apache, PHP 7.3, PHP-FPM, Docker

Comment: Did you try : PHP_ERROR_REPORTING="E_ALL" ?

Comment: No luck with quoting the string either

Answer (score 0):

First you should run

```
docker exec -ti your_image:tagged  env | grep "PHP_"
```

and see what is *actually set* inside the running container.
(*beware*, if you try to `echo $PHP_ERROR_REPORTING` it will return empty env-var, because the shell with no entrypoint is `sh`, not `bash`)

> As I have been playing, it seems like I can set any boolean value using an ENV vairable via but cannot set string values in the same way.

Actually should be the opposite: in Linux shell scripts/expansion there's no Boolean type, just Strings.

Try first to ensure that you environment variables have the value that you expect; then proceed from there in debugging whether is a problem with FPM or the INI file (although that's quite unlikely).